# Show "Login or Register to do something" link for anonymous users on all inaccessible forms

Tags: users

Some modules will show forms in a page or tab for roles with the relevant permissions, and these forms don't show up for roles without the relevant permissions by default.

So, my question is: Is there a universal and configurable (preferred) way to show Login or Register to do more link in the positions of these forms, instead of simply not showing the forms at all. And It is best to show up the Login or Register form in a modal form.
It seems [Redirect 403 to User Login](https://drupal.org/project/r4032login) and [LoginToboggan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) cannot achieve my goal.